# markdown.sty --- embedding latex recursively

Tags: shell-escape, markdown

I am using overleaf.  It conveniently makes it easy to include `markdown.sty` (which requires `--shell-escape`).  I can include book chapters with `\markdownInput{chaptername.md}`, which allows my latex-ignorant coauthor to collaborate with me over overleaf just writing markdown in the chapter.

markdown can pass through unambiguous latex commands.  This makes it easy to include such commands as `\clearpage`.  It also works indirectly for exhibits.  I have an `exhibits.tex` file, in which I define all my exhibits:

```
\providecommand{\figuretwentytwo}{%
    \begin{figure}
       \myspecialcaption[mylabel]{My Figure 22}

       There is all sorts of figure stuff here.

    \end{figure}
 }
```

Then I insert the latex macro for each figure in `chaptername.md`.  it works, but it is getting unwieldy.  We have dozens of figures and tables.

is there a way to tell markdown.sty that I want to fence off an area in `chaptername.md` for pure latex, never to be translated by markdown and only to be passed back as unadulterated latex for typesetting?

````
 chapter.md:

 # Chapter 2

 This is **nice** and simple markdown.  We will do

 1. one
 2. two
 3. and three.

 Let me show you in a figure.

 ```latex passback
     \providecommand[mylabel]{\figuretwentytwo}{%
    \begin{figure}
       \myspecialcaption{My Figure 22}

       There is all sorts of figure stuff here.

    \end{figure}
 }
 ```

 [Figure ](mylabel)  does stuff.
````

This may not be feasible, but it would scratch a bad itch.

Comment: it looks like you could use `\input` instead of `\markdownInout` then surround the \markdownbegin .. `\makrkdownend` around markdown and let tex be in the other parts

Comment: thx, david.  would work, but most of it would be surrounded "perversely"...from the start to the exhibits, and then from the end of the exhibit to the end of the file.   c'est la vis.  either my current solution or this one is workable.  just an itch...